# What is the relationship between Ekman transport and volume transport?

Tags: oceanography, ocean-currents, ocean-models

Ekman transport components are in the zonal and meridional direction.
Along the coast of California, which is an eastern boundary coast, say there is wind flowing down the coast in the meridional direction (towards the equator).
The zonal Ekman component would be pointed towards the right of that wind vector causing water along that boundary to move offshore (so away from the coast), right?

But what is the relationship between the magnitude of Ekman transport (both components), zonal or meridional Ekman transport with the volume transport say taken along a cross section at one latitude along the California coast?

Basically how is the volume transport and Ekman transport (zonal, meridional, or magnitude) related?
Thank you and let me know if the question needs to be elaborated!